# Kind of #if (Debug Symbol) but for web.config file

Tags: asp.net, web-config

I would like to use different  section for debug and release configuration.
tried to use "web.config transform" functionality but it works great only for deploying. and not when i just want to build and execute the application locally.

can i add a condition to the web.config for choosing the right ?

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

If you are using Visual Studio 2010 then you can have them on different config files.

Check http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wx0123s5.aspx